# I erased hardware address of wifi device in NetworkManager. How can I find it again?

Tags: centos, wifi, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

I was trying to fix a limited connectivity wifi connection and erased the hardware address of wifi device in NetworkManager by mistake. I cannot get wifi to work and thought changing those settings would help. I am new to linux and cannot figure this out. Also new to centos 7 which I am running.

Comment: what do you mean by erasing the hardware address? Which command did you use to do that?

Comment: I went into nmtui and edited the wifi device configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you managed to get NetworkManager to change the ethernet address of your wifi card, it's not lost: it's stored in some ROM in the NIC.

To retrieve the original address without having to reload the kernel module or reboot, while keeping NetworkManager out of it, you can use the command `ethtool` (from package of the same name). The NIC driver has to support the operation. Just replace with the correct interface name:

```
# ethtool --show-permaddr wlan0
Permanent address: 00:13:de:ad:ca:fe
```

(result was redacted)

I'm simply answering the title of the question, I hope this can help you correct your issues.

Comment: Cannot read permanent address: No such device

Comment: what is the actual name of your wireless interface? probably not `wlan0`. Please replace `wlan0` with the actual name. You can find the name among the interfaces displayed with `ip link show`. It probably still starts with the letter `w`.

Comment: The only interfaces that show are lo, enpl1s0, virbr0, and virbr0-nic.  The weird thing is, I had wi-fi working about 6 months ago but then it stopped working. I switched to MS on partition and only recently found a renewed interest to try and use Centos7.  I used command "ls /lib/firmware/rtlwifi" and it lists stuff there, I assume wifi adapter drivers. But I can't figure out how to use them.

Comment: I went into windows and got the mac address of the wifi adapter.  Then I rebooted into Linux and applied it in NetworkManager. So that is solved, but now how do I get my wifi working again?

Comment: Oh well I don't know. I even don't know which is your wifi interface (is it enpl1s0 ?). If you don't know either yourself...